# Python test run under Pytest does not catch CalledProcessError exceptions correctly

Tags: python, exception, subprocess, pytest, doctest

I am at the moment facing a weird behaviour when running Python doctests in Pytest (`py.test`). The following snippet highlights the bevaviour.

- The doctests *do pass* when the script is invoked via `python2.7 ./weirdpytestbehaviour_test.py`.
- The doctests *do not pass* when the script is invoked via `py.test ./weirdpytestbehaviour_test.py --doctest-modules --tb=short`.
- If I change the statement `except CalledProcessError as e:` into `except Exception as e:` the doctests then also pass with `py.test`.

It seems as py.test has some special treatment for the `CalledProcessError` exception type. It is very unintuitive that the code takes a different evaluation path when executed in `py.test`. 
How can I control or tweak that behaviour?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
# file: 'weirdpytestbehaviour_test.py'
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError

def func(success):
    """The worker function.

    >>> func(success=True)
    >>> func(success=False)
    Ouch!
    Special treatment of this particular failure...
    """
    try:
        # Now invoke a subprocess
        if success:
            # Will always succeed and return with an exit code of 0
            check_output('echo "Hello!"; exit 0', shell=True)
        else:
            # Will always succeed and return with an exit code of 1
            check_output('echo "Ouch!"; exit 1', shell=True)

    # Does not catch the exception under pytest
    # 'except Exception as e:' would work as expected
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.output),
        if "Ouch!" in e.output:
            print("Special treatment of this particular failure...")
        else:
            raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The output of py.test in the failure case (trying to catch CalledProcessError above) is as follows:

```
$ py.test ./weirdpytestbehaviour_test.py --doctest-modules --tb=short 
Test session starts (platform: linux2, Python 2.7.6, pytest 3.4.2, pytest-sugar 0.9.1)
[...]

007 The worker function.
008 
009     >>> func(success=True)
010 
011     >>> func(success=False)
UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION: CalledProcessError()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1315, in __run
    compileflags, 1) in test.globs

  File "<doctest experiments.weirdpytestbehaviour_test.func[1]>", line 1, in <module>

  File "weirdpytestbehaviour_test.py", line 22, in func
    check_output('echo "Ouch!"; exit 1', shell=True)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)

CalledProcessError: Command 'echo "Ouch!"; exit 1' returned non-zero exit status 1

weirdpytestbehaviour_test.py:11: UnexpectedException

weirdpytestbehaviour_test.py ⨯                                                                                                                                                                                        100% ██████████

Results (0.19s):
       1 failed
         - weirdpytestbehaviour_test.py:11 [doctest] weirdpytestbehaviour_test.func
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue with your exact code, neither on Fedora 27 nor on CentOS 7 nor on MacOS High Sierra. Looks like some weird cache issue - try deleting all `__pycache__` dirs, also `.cache/` and `.pytest_cache/` dirs.

Comment: Hm, thanks. I will check that. What version of pytest were you using?

Comment: I recreated your setup with `pytest==3.4.2` and `pytest-sugar==0.9.1`, although I don't have the exact version of `python2`. Nevertheless, tested with Python 2.7.5, 2.7.10 and 2.7.14 on different machines with no problem.

Comment: I cleaned the cache via `--cache-clear` and also deleted all `__pycache__` directories beforehand but the issue remains. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Well, nothing besides creating a new virtualenv and a new file with your code from above, see if the error is reproducible. If yes, you have an issue with your system or system python installation - try reproducing on another machine (a VM is fine). If not, there must be a  difference between two environments, mybe some additional code or installed packages that are interfering.

Comment: Thanks for your help! - I solved it eventually, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I solved this issue by uninstalling and re-installing not only pytest but also the plugins I used. After that it was working again.

Cleaning the cache (`__pycache__`) did not have an effect. Apparently there was something wrong with the installation of pytest and its plugins.